# iTextSharp Input string was not in a correct format css error

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I have been trying to get my MVC application te create pdf files based on MVC Views. I got this working with plain html. But i would also like to iclude my css files that i use for the browser. Now some of them work but with one i get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

I am using the following code:

```
var data = GetHtml(new IndexModel(Context), "~\\Views\\Home\\Index.cshtml", "");
            using (var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {

                //define output control HTML
                var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                TextReader xmlString = new StringReader(data);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c:\\tmp\\my.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

                //open doc
                document.Open();

                // register all fonts in current computer
                FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();

                // Set factories
                var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
                htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

                // Set css
                ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
                cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/elements.css"), true);
                cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/style.css"), true);
                cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/jquery-ui.css"), true);
                // Export
                IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
                var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
                var xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);
                xmlParse.Parse(xmlString);
                xmlParse.Flush();

                document.Close();

            }
```

the string "data" is correct and has no issues, the problem lies with the AddCssFile().
If i create the pdf without and css files everything works, but including the css files triggers the error.

Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does it break with all three CSS files or just one specific one? What version of iTextSharp and XMLWorker are you using? This one might be hard to troubleshoot remotely, I'd suggest getting the source for both and step through the debugger to see what's throwing that exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer, but by looking at the error you are getting back, I would try two different approaches.

1. Move the

   `cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/elements.css"), true);`

   To something like

   `var cssPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/elements.css"), true);
   cssResolver.AddCssFile(cssPath);`

Then set a breakpoint and look at the values being returned for cssPath.  Make sure they are accurate and do not contain any odd characters.

Second approach...  If all else fails, try giving an absolute URL to the CSS resource such as http://yourdomain.com/cssPath instead of a file system path.

If either of those two appraoches help you, then you can use it to determine the actual problem and then refactor it to your hearts content after that.

UPDATE ------------------------------------------------------------------>
According to the documentation, you need an absolute URL for the file, so Server.MapPath won't work.

```
addCssFile

void addCssFile(String href,
                boolean isPersistent)
                throws CssResolverException
Add a
Parameters:
href - the link to the css file ( an absolute uri )
isPersistent - true if the added css should not be deleted on a call to clear
Throws:
CssResolverException - thrown if something goes wrong
```

In that case, I would try using something like :

```
public string AbsoluteContent(string contentPath)
    {
        var path = Url.Content(contentPath);
        var url = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, path);

        return url.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

and use it like such :

```
var cssPath = AbsoluteContent("~/Content/embeddedCss/yourcssfile.css");
```

Comment: Hi David, ik tried both of your tips and still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post what the cssPath variable was set to when you stepped through it?

Comment: C:\\ProjectenTFS\\mgz\\Main\\MgzApp2\\Content\\elements.css